# Can't able to static compile QT 6.4.0 using Mingw

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

When I was trying to compile QT 6.4.0 static with Mingw I had and error with fxc, after spending time found it was an error because it couldn't able to find fxc.exe so I added fxc to path from windows kits (10), after adding it fixed that error but now I'm getting different errors.

**Configure:** `configure.bat -release -static -static-runtime -no-pch -optimize-size -opengl desktop -platform win32-g++ -prefix "C:\qt\6.4.0static\qt-static" -skip webengine -nomake tools -nomake tests -nomake examples`

**My OS:** Windows 11 Pro (21H2).

**For more log details:** [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UrqsARLJ)

```
qsgd3d12engine.cpp: In member function 'D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE QSGD3D12CPUDescriptorHeapManager::allocate(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE)':
qsgd3d12engine.cpp:121:41: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'long long unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]
  121 |             for (int bucket = 0; bucket < _countof(heap.freeMap); ++bucket)
      |                                         ^
qsgd3d12engine.cpp:157:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'long long unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]
  157 |     for (int i = 1; i < _countof(heap.freeMap); ++i)
      |                       ^
qsgd3d12engine.cpp: In function 'void getHardwareAdapter(IDXGIFactory1*, IDXGIAdapter1**)':
qsgd3d12engine.cpp:224:83: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  224 |             HRESULT hr = D3D12CreateDevice(adapter.Get(), fl, _uuidof(ID3D12Device), nullptr);
      |                                                                                   ^
qsgd3d12engine.cpp:224:63: error: '_uuidof' was not declared in this scope
  224 |             HRESULT hr = D3D12CreateDevice(adapter.Get(), fl, _uuidof(ID3D12Device), nullptr);
      |                                                               ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winbase.h:2811,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:70,
                 from C:/Qt/dev/Qt/src/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qt_windows.h:64,
                 from C:\Qt\dev\Qt\src\qtbase\include/QtCore/qt_windows.h:1,
                 from C:/Qt/dev/Qt/src/qtbase/src/gui/opengl/qopengl.h:49,
                 from C:\Qt\dev\Qt\src\qtbase\include/QtGui/qopengl.h:1,
                 from C:/Qt/dev/Qt/src/qtdeclarative/src/quick/scenegraph/coreapi/qsggeometry.h:44,
                 from ..\..\..\..\include\QtQuick/qsggeometry.h:1,
                 from qsgd3d12engine_p.h:57,
                 from qsgd3d12engine.cpp:40:
qsgd3d12engine.cpp:241:80: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  241 |         if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12CreateDevice(adapter.Get(), fl, _uuidof(ID3D12Device), nullptr))) {
      |                                                                                ^
qsgd3d12engine.cpp:241:60: error: '_uuidof' was not declared in this scope
  241 |         if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12CreateDevice(adapter.Get(), fl, _uuidof(ID3D12Device), nullptr))) {
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~
```

**EDIT:** Fixed the issues, check the marked answer for more details.

Comment: The problem is `__uuidof` is an MSVC extension, I think MinGW [also supports it](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-tools/widl/include/guiddef.h#L51) but I don't know why Qt uses `_uuidof` (one underscore). I think these related links will help you: [build failure - '_uuidof' was not declared in this scope](https://forum.qt.io/topic/128587/build-failure-_uuidof-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/7), [qt5.15.2-qtdeclarative.patch](https://gist.github.com/cristianadam/3328bfadbdd17838717f4f1919e470ee). Also, it could be built easier using `vcpkg`.

Comment: @thedemons Thank you, that fixed the uuidof error still having errors with DirectX (https://pastebin.com/6naPCWQc).

Comment: can you try to include `d3d12sdklayers.h` and `initguid.h` like the [qt5.15.2-qtdeclarative.patch](https://gist.github.com/cristianadam/3328bfadbdd17838717f4f1919e470ee)?

Comment: ID3D12Debug wasn't declared in this scope has been fixed by including d3d12sdklayers.h header file from windows sdk inside the qsgd3d12engine.cpp 
referred from https://gitter.im/msys2/msys2?at=5f8ab4d861007f7d1b784e24.

Comment: Also include `combaseapi.h` for the [IID_PPV_ARGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) macro

Comment: qsgd3d12engine.cpp compiled without initguid.h.

Comment: So is it solved? You should add an answer to how you did it and mark it as accepted for other people who found the same problem.

Comment: Will mark it as solved, once it finishes compiling fully. Thank you for helping me @thedemons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To fix __uuidof error with mingw follow the steps from this link:**

https://forum.qt.io/topic/128587/build-failure-_uuidof-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/7

**To fix QT DirectX issue follow this steps:**

1. Download Windows SDK from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/. (I downloaded SDK for windows 11 (my OS)).
2. open this file pathToQTSource\qtdeclarative\plugins\scenegraph\d3d12\qsgd3d12engine.cpp in your preferred editor and add this line `#include <d3d12sdklayers.h>` at include section and save it.
3. That's it.

**To fix another error I've faced while compiling mfvideorenderercontrol.cpp:**

1. Goto pathToQtSource\qtmultimedia\src\plugins\wmf\player\mfvideorendercontrol.cpp and change the access modifier from **protected** to **public** of `void customEvent(QEvent *event)` function (declared at `class PresentEvent`).

Thanks to [@thedemons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13253010/thedemons) for helping me to fix the issue.